# Microcontroller interrupt priority changing

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Is it recommended to change interrupt priority setting?  I know for example Texas instrument MSP430 board has a hard-wired vector table so it is not possible to change them. Some architectures support static or dynamic priority selection, but as far as I know it is not recommended. What are disadvantages of changing the priorities?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. (Note that for MSP430 you even cannot change the interrupt priority.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interrupt priority affects the scheduling and pre-emption of of interrupts; this can be critical in some *hard real-time* systems with dead-lines in the order of microseconds or less.  Since Linux is generally unsuited to such applications in any case, if interrupt priority matters to the correct operation of your application you probably would not use Linux.